# C# code to find whether today Date lies between or equal to the two other specified date

Tags: c#-3.0

I have two date as
Date1= 7/28/2014 and Date2=7/31/2014.

I want to check whether today date i.e 7/31/2014 lies between the above mentioned data.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: `Date1 < DateTime.Now && DateTime.Now < Date2`?

Comment: This really could be answered a million different ways, I think you should include steps that you've taken to figure this out rather than waiting for an answer.

Comment: Yes....i took 28 and 31 from date1 and date2 then using if condition,i compared the two date.It works,but fails in case of date like 31 and 1 i.e month end date with next month start date

Comment: @user2720620 as a hint, maybe consider creating `DateTime` objects from your dates and then using their properties i.e. `.Date` to compare, you're obviously going to need a `myDate.Date between startDate.Date and endDate.Date` sort of thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :)

```
        DateTime dat1 = Convert.ToDateTime("7/28/2014");
        DateTime dat2 = Convert.ToDateTime("8/1/2014");

        DateTime today = Convert.ToDateTime(DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyy"));

        if (today > dat1 && today < dat2)
        {

           // between
        }
        else
        {
            // lies between
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your problem lays in Time part of DateTime...if Date2 is 7/31/2014 0:00:00 and Now is 7/31/2014 11:30:00 then Date2 < Now...consider using DateTime::Date property